# After running an animation in xcode I need the UIImage to change to a different static image

Tags: xcode, swift, animation, static, uiimage

So the code under the didRecieveMemoryWarning doesn't seem to be called after the animation is completed. What I want the animation to do is when the UIbutton is pressed it shows a series of UIImages being shuffled through and then after 6 repeat counts it stops on a random static image based on:

```
    @IBAction func playRoundTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    let firstRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(2) + 1

    let firstCardString:String = String(format: "side%i", firstRandomNumber)

    self.firstDiceImageView.image = UIImage(named: firstCardString)

}
```

However for some reason everytime the animation completes it goes back to the "card_default" static image instead of the "side%i" randomized image.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Setting UIImages to Default
    self.firstDiceImageView.image = UIImage(named: "card_default")
    self.secondDiceImageView.image = UIImage(named: "card_default")
    self.thirdDiceImageView.image = UIImage(named: "card_default")
    self.forthDiceImageView.image = UIImage(named: "card_default")

    //Animation For Loop
    for i in 1...4
    {
        myImages.append(UIImage(named: "\(i)")!)

    }

    firstDiceImageView.animationImages = myImages
    firstDiceImageView.animationRepeatCount = 6
    firstDiceImageView.stopAnimating()

    secondDiceImageView.animationImages = myImages
    secondDiceImageView.animationRepeatCount = 6

    thirdDiceImageView.animationImages = myImages
    thirdDiceImageView.animationRepeatCount = 6

    forthDiceImageView.animationImages = myImages
    forthDiceImageView.animationRepeatCount = 6



}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func playRoundTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    let firstRandomNumber = arc4random_uniform(2) + 1

    let firstCardString:String = String(format: "side%i", firstRandomNumber)

    self.firstDiceImageView.image = UIImage(named: firstCardString)

}
```

Comment: how do u expect the button method to get called on its own ?

Comment: @IBAction func playRoundTapped(sender: UIButton) is this the button method? i'm very new to coding

Comment: yes. IF you want the code inside of it to get called, place that code under the imegeview animation code.